# Ionic 2 html does not reload though binding

Tags: angular, typescript, binding, ionic2

when text changes on one of my pages I create an event like so:

```
onTextChange(){
this.storage.set('block_preferences', this.Block_Settings_Array); 
this.events.publish('update:needed');
}
```

on another page I subscribe to an event like so:

```
     events.subscribe('update:needed', () => {
     console.log("re_loading week")
     this.data_loaded = false; 
     this.loadSchedule();
  });
```

this all works and it calls "this.loadSchedule()" (I can tell because of console prints "re_loading week")

this.loadSchedule() calls MakeTable(), and at the end of MakeTable() there are these lines

```
 console.log(this.Week_Schedule_Arr)
 console.log("WOW")
 this.data_loaded = true;
```

the "Week_Schedule_Arr" is an array that is updated based on the new "block_preferences" stored. I can check that it is indeed updated because the console prints the array and "WOW" is printed out.

My html however:

```
     <div  *ngIf="data_loaded"> 


     <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="Week">


          <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let data of Week_Schedule_Arr" value="{{data.ID}}">
          {{data.ID}}
      </ion-segment-button>

      </ion-segment>
     </div>




      <div [ngSwitch]="Week">

         <div *ngFor="let data of Week_Schedule_Arr">

             <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="data.ID">

              <ion-item *ngFor="let block of data.Arr" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': block.Color}">


                {{block.Name}}    {{block.Start}} => {{block.End}}  

           </ion-item>


       </ion-list>


    </div>

    </div>
```

Does not work. When I transition to the page I see the segment buttons and none of the data, which makes me think the "ngIf" isn't binding.

Thoughts?

Comment: Isn't this.storage.set async? I guess you should have to resolve the promise thet .set() method returns and than broadcast the event.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler The "this.Week_Schedule_Arr" is already updated (I can check the values in console to make sure they match with what I just set) so I don't think that is the problem, though it would be better programming technique.

Comment: Inject ChangeDetecetorRef in to constructor and call its detectChanges function. Since this event handling is happening outside of the rendering procedure it doesn't know that the page needs to be reload unless you directly tell it so.